# Selenium working too slow

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

We are using the following code snippet in order to pass to the next test step safely.

```
private void waitTextPresent(String toBeExpectedText) throws InterruptedException {
         for (int second = 0;; second++) {
                if (second >= 60) {
                       // not found
                }
                try {

                       if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText()
                       .matches(toBeExpectedText))
                       break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
         }
   }
```

We are using `Selenium 2.44.0` (This seems to be the stable release). `Firefox` version is 37.0 because v38 and v39 have problems and previous versions are slow.

However, even this code snippet runs too slow that the total time for testing is too long. Is there any way to re-write this snippet in a more effective way?

Comment: Have you set any implicitwait time in your code anywhere? cause that will again add that time to your loops everytime element is not found. Just a mere guess. Anyhow best way is to use ExpectedConditions as pointed by @Vinoth S.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Expected Conditions.](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

For your requirement, just this 1 line of code will do.

`new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, txt))`;

Comment: Thank you. I'll just try that and let you know.

Comment: We tried your suggestion. Execution time didn't change but it was also useful because we got rid of thread and for loop. The main problem is, Selenium cannot find the elements fast. At this point, the problem might be related with RemoteWebDriver. Any more suggestion?